# How to connect to pi that is connected to internet via android usb tethering

Tags: networking

I have raspberry pi zero connected to my wifi via my android phone's usb internet sharing, and pc connected to router via ethernet cable.

On raspberry I can connect to internet, ping router, even ping my pc, however I am unable to ping raspberry from my pc.

How to connect to my raspberry from pc?

Comment: Not Pi specific.

Comment: This is really a question about software on your phone; the brand of hardware of the connected device is irrelevant.  https://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **NORMAL** (at least on most OS, presumably including Android).

You can have **EITHER** ICS **OR** `ssh` etc access to the Pi, not BOTH.

It is not impossible to have both, but this requires additional software and complex configuration on the host system, and this is off-topic for this site. NOTHING you can do on the Pi is going to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have your `raspberry pi zero` connected to your android phone with `USB-Tethering` and your phone is connected through wifi to your router and the internet. So it is member of your local network and can see your pc. With this over tethering your pi can  also get to the internet and to your pc. But `USB-Tethering` is a generic connection to the internet. It can also use your mobile phone connection to your phone provider without using wifi. So it is very likely that it has a NAT connection for security reasons. With this you can go out to the internet but not from internet to your phone. That is why your pc cannot reach your pi. To solve this you have to connect direct to your router with the pi e.g. with a USB to ethernet or USB to wifi dongle.